# Combine two column as new and use that column in the same mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am trying this Mysql Query -

```
SELECT pan_1, dp_id, client_id, CONCAT(dp_id,client_id) AS ref, name_s,  bonds
FROM `holding_details`
WHERE `date` = '2015-10-23'
AND comp_code = '33'
AND ref NOT IN 
(SELECT CONCAT(dp_id,client_id) AS ref FROM `promoters` WHERE comp_code = '33')
GROUP BY pan_1
ORDER BY bonds DESC
```

By reading this above query you simply understand what result I want. I have two saparate column dp_id and client_id in both the table with same name. I want some result from 'holding_details' table except those which are present in 'promoters' table on the condition of dp_id and client_id column, I combine them because its make them unique record. I tried above MySql query but it shows me "unknown column ref" error. Please tell me it is not possible to use the combine column in the same query and how can I achieve that result. Thanks

Comment: What i understand is. YOu want the select data from two diffrent tables? 
Tried left join already?

Comment: No don't want to join the table. I just want data from holding_details table but only those dp_id and client_id which are not present in promoters table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe to your problem....
Better use [NOT EXIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html). It has a way better chance for using an index than your CONCAT()-approach....

```
SELECT
    pan_1, dp_id, client_id, name_s,  bonds
FROM
    `holding_details` as hd
WHERE
    hd.`date` = '2015-10-23'
AND
    hd.comp_code = '33'
AND
  NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            promoters as p
        WHERE
            p.comp_code = '33'
            AND hd.dp_id=p.dp_id
            AND hd.client_id=p.client_id
    )
GROUP BY
    pan_1
ORDER BY
    bonds DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT pan_1, dp_id, client_id, CONCAT(dp_id,client_id) AS ref, name_s, bonds
FROM `holding_details` d
WHERE `date` = '2015-10-23'
AND comp_code = '33'
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 'x' FROM `promoters` p
  WHERE p.comp_code = '33' 
        AND p.dp_id = d.dp_id
        AND p.client_id = d.client_id)
GROUP BY pan_1
ORDER BY bonds DESC
```

This should work too: Specify just the two columns (without CONCAT!) and also return two columns from the select:

```
SELECT pan_1, dp_id, client_id, CONCAT(dp_id,client_id) AS ref, name_s, bonds
FROM `holding_details`
WHERE `date` = '2015-10-23'
AND comp_code = '33'
AND (dp_id, client_id) NOT IN 
  (SELECT dp_id, client_id) AS ref FROM `promoters` WHERE comp_code = '33')
GROUP BY pan_1
ORDER BY bonds DESC
```

Your own attempt could have worked too if you use not the alias `ref`, but the expression itself. I'd prefer the one above, though. Concatting makes it less clear and less efficient regarding the use of indexes. The query above can be very efficient if you have the right indexes. Anyway, here it is:

```
SELECT pan_1, dp_id, client_id, CONCAT(dp_id,client_id) AS ref, name_s,  bonds
FROM `holding_details`
WHERE `date` = '2015-10-23'
AND comp_code = '33'
AND CONCAT(dp_id,client_id) NOT IN 
(SELECT CONCAT(dp_id,client_id) AS ref FROM `promoters` WHERE comp_code = '33')
GROUP BY pan_1
ORDER BY bonds DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query,

```
SELECT pan_1, hd.`dp_id`, hd.`client_id`, CONCAT(hd.`dp_id`,hd.`client_id`) AS ref, name_s,  bonds  
FROM `holding_details` as hd
LEFT JOIN `promoters` as p  on p.`dp_id` = hd.`dp_id` AND p.`client_id` =  hd.`client_id`
WHERE hd.`date` = '2015-10-23' 
AND hd.`comp_code` = '33'
AND p.`dp_id` <> hd.`dp_id` 
AND p.`client_id` <>  hd.`client_id`
GROUP BY pan_1
ORDER BY bonds DESC
```

Comment: This needs a WHERE clause for isnull(p.dp_id) or something similar or else the result will contain a lot more records than anticipated....  (otherwise it's a viable solution; the query optimizer is quite good at "understanding" such queries)